# Displaying a boolean value in an angularjs grid column

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working on a web app and I need to display if something is being backed up or not and want to start off by just displaying a boolean value in the column.

Right now, this is some of what I have:

**JS:**

```
$scope.backupStatus = false;

$scope.enableBackup = function() {
   $scope.selectedProject.backupStatus = true;
};

$scope.disableBackup = function() {
   $scope.selectedProject.backupStatus = false;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">

   <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
     <span>{{selectedProject.backupStatus}}</span>
   </div>

</div>
```

Obviously, what I have right now is not working and nothing is being displayed in the column. I am just wondering what conventions I need to follow to get this to display in the column.

**To clarify**: The enableBackup and DisableBackup functions are being called when there is a button that is clicked in a different part of my grid

Comment: what happens if you display {{selectedProject}}?

Comment: I'd guess that there isn't a reference to the controller in scope when the html is rendered. Where/how are you loading your controller?

Comment: @MikeFeltman In the js I have a function called "getGridColumnDefs()" that calls for a cell template, and in my backup column def I have my "cellTemplate" variable pointing to my html file

Comment: Um. Ok, but where/how are you loading the controller?

Comment: @MikeFeltman sorry, did not read that correctly the first time around. I am loading it in a separate "app.js" file

Comment: @Dakota Maker, Can you please share your grid code. becuase it will helpfull to get issue correctly. as per me there is not problem in js. problem should be in grid configration

Comment: Where are you loading it in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the confusion is it isn't immediately clear that you are using ui-grid. I suggest clearing that up / adding the 'angular-ui-grid' tag.

This should work:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">

   <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
     <span>{{ grid.appScope.selectedProject.backupStatus }}</span>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: and this should work in addition to the changes in the js suggested by Gaurav below?

Comment: Not necessarily. selectedProject.backupStatus would have to exist in order to show a value, however, what that is showing is selecting a default project on load that is essentially null, with a backup status of false. If the page loads without a selected project, and the user selects one, at that point, it would have a value. I'd have to see more code to understand if initializing it makes sense. (why would enableBackup() be available if there was no selected project. What would you be enabling in that case?)

Comment: What I've provided shows you how to access values from the parent scope (your controller) within the child scope (that of the grid). $scope.myValue -> grid.appScope.myValue.

Comment: wonderful, that gave me what I needed to get going in the right way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize **$scope.selectedProject**

```
$scope.selectedProject = {};
$scope.selectedProject.backupStatus = false;

$scope.enableBackup = function() {
   $scope.selectedProject.backupStatus = true;
};

$scope.disableBackup = function() {
   $scope.selectedProject.backupStatus = false;
};
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is still not working. However, your suggestion does make sense to me. I'm assuming I might just have something else that is incorrect/off

Comment: @DakotaMaker Is the div that you showed above inside a parent element that has an `ng-app` directive?

Comment: @DakotaMaker can you make a plunkar it would be helpful.